# How to delete excel temporary file "~$" in document library without delete permission

Tags: 2016, excel, delete

I have a document library which the normal user can only create and modify the files, they cannot delete them. But when they modify the files, there will be some temporary files "~$" being created in the document library and cannot be deleted by normal user automatically. May I know if there is any solution in this case? Thank  you so much !!!!